# ClassCastException when casting Object[] array to generic type array in Java

Tags: java, classcastexception

Hi I'm very new to Java and in this code, I think I'm not creating the Bag correctly in the Main? Please help thanks!

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at mid.Bag.(Bag.java:12)
    at mid.Bag.main(Bag.java:91)**

```
        public class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
      private int MAX_ITEMS = 10; // initial array size
      private int size;
      private T[] data;

      public Bag( ) {
        data = (T []) new Object[MAX_ITEMS];
        size = 0;
      }

      public void add(T newItem) {
        // check if it's full, then extend (array resizing)
        if (size == data.length) {
          T[ ] temp = (T [ ] ) new Object[data.length*2];
          for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            temp[i] = data[i];
          // reassign data to point to temp
          data = temp;
        }
        // then do the assignment
        data[size++] = newItem; // assign newItem in the next-available slot
      }

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new BagIterator();
  }

 /***************************
  * nested class BagIterator
  ***************************/
   class BagIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    // instance member
    private int index;

    // (0) constructor
    public BagIterator() {
      index = 0;
    }
    // (1)
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return (index < size); // size in the outer Bag<E>
    }
    // (2)
    public T next() {
      /*
      T temp = data[index]; // save the element value
      index++; // increment index
      return temp;
      */
      return data[index++];
    }
      public static void main(String[ ] args) {
          Bag<String> bag1=new Bag<String>();

          bag1.add("good");
          bag1.add("fortune");
          bag1.add("billionarie");
          for (String x: bag1)
              System.out.println(x);

      }
```

Comment: You need to update your code for `iterator()` as the code does not compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're creating an `Object[]` and then trying to cast it to `T[]`, which the compiler is converting to a cast to `Comparable[]` (using the raw `Comparable` type) due to your constraint on T.

Arrays and generics don't work terribly nicely together, basically.

It would probably be simpler to make your `data` field just an `Object[]` and cast individual values where necessary.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your reply, is there a way to keep my field and adjust my bag type in the main?

Comment: @Robert, it would be nice to see your `iterator()` method to answer to this. Please add it to your question.

Comment: So you just need to use `return (T)data[index++];` in your `next()` method and keep the `data` as `Object[]`. Your `main` method will not notice anything. Also it's easier to use `((List<T>)Arrays.asList(data)).iterator()` instead of implementing your own iterator.

Comment: @Robert: I don't really know what you mean by that... and your response of "it's not working" to Tagir doesn't really give enough information to help you. I suspect you should create a new question for your ongoing problems - your initial question was about a ClassCastException, and that's now solved. Stack Overflow is geared towards one question per post - don't forget that we're trying to create a repository of information for future readers, not just solving all your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
data = (T []) new Object[MAX_ITEMS];
```

you are constructing an `Object` array and trying to cast it to `T[]`. But you have declared that `T` inherits from `Comparable`. So use:

```
data = (T []) new Comparable[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Comment: Hi khelwood, thanks for your reply, is there a way to keep my field and adjust my bag type in the main?

Comment: You can still keep your field. Just construct it as an array of `Comparable` instead of an array of `Object`. Or take out `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and replace it with `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably rewrite your constructor as well:

```
public Bag(Class<T> c, int s) {
    // Use Array native method to create array of a type only known at run time
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final T[] dataArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, s);
    this.data = dataArray;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Bag<String> bag1 = new Bag<>(String.class,10);
```

That should also work, IMO. The instances of T must be comparable in any case.